# Unable to retrieve an Image from database in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have stored images in my local mdf database in bytes. I am having troubles with retrieving it to view. I am using ASP.net and c#.

> Error 1   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Image' and no extension method 'Image' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 2   'Image' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'System.Drawing.Image' and 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image'

***Below is my code***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

private void LoadImage()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Donald\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DesktopApplication\DesktopApplication\Student_CB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            //Fetching top recipe     
            string query = "Select Image FROM Recipe_Image where Image_Name = '"+VeganLbl1.Text+"'";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            byte[] img = (byte[])dt.Rows[0][0];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
            Image1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            da.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {



        }

        con.Close();
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to complete this and get it working. Once i am able to do this im pretty much good with all my code.

Also yes i am aware i am not using parameters. This will come shortly once i have been able to display the image.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the issue you're getting? It looks like you're not returning anything. Also, make sure all Disposables are properly disposed.

Comment: Are you looking for `Image.FromStream(ms)` ? - You should use `using` for those SQL objects, they require disposal.

Comment: @AlexK. I have tried using Image1.ImageUrl = Image.FromStream(ms); but it doesnt like the FromStream part. It states it doesnt have a definition

Comment: You need `using System.Drawing;` and perhaps a reference to it too

Comment: @AlexK. how would i reference to it? also i have updated the code above

Comment: Er and ImageUrl probably is not correct as it will want a string or uri

Comment: Please remove that catch statement that simply hides errors. For all you know, someone may have typed `';drop table Recipe_Image;--` in that textbox and deleted your table. That's a hint to use parameterized queries

Comment: @AlexK. could you form up an answer for me? so i can see it please.

Comment: Post the *full* exception, including its call stack. You can get this easily with `Exception.ToString()`. If you get a compilation error post the exact error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos im so confused.

Comment: Remove one of these imports: `using System.Drawing;`
`using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`. Preferably one that you're not using. And just refer to the fully qualified path for Image, if required.

Comment: @ManoDestra i tried this but both are being used. I cut out one, part of it fails.

Comment: Then just refer to the ones from the using you remove by their fully qualified namespaces and class names. Or use a using alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems

1. You are using the wrong image class for `Image.FromStream(ms)`. Instead write: `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)`. (but you don't need this anyway)
2. `Image.FromStream(ms)` returns an `image` object and `Image1.ImageUrl` wants a string path.

What you have to do is point `Image1.ImageUrl` to a page that writes the image byte array to the Response stream.

In you code point to page `GetImage.aspx`

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "GetImage.aspx";
```

In the `GetImage` page write the memory stream with the image to the response output stream:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"; //Or whatever it is
Response.Buffer = true;
ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to make this more HTML manageable therefore stream the SQL binary to file and display it with HTML code.
Try using `System.IO` namespace to write your image to temporary server location then display it with HTML markup using temp file path. Remove temporary files on session end. Let me know if you need code.